# How to obtain blocked panel (p:panel or ui:gridContainer) by default using p:blockUI?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, blockui

I have checkbox p:selectBooleanCheckbox on the JSF page, which show or hide some panel using p:blockUI
How to get page with blocked panel on load?

Comment: "How to get page with  blocked panel on load"? elaborate

Comment: I did it during 3 days.
But seems that it is not so simple.
Maybe js, but I have no experience in it :(

Comment: But I am not still sure what exactly you're after?

Comment: If you could explain your problem I might be able to help you

Comment: Okey. I try.
I have the jsf page with selectBooleanCheckbox, gridContainer and p:blockUI component. The blockui must block gridcontainer if checkbox unchecked.
The flow is: on page load, checkbox value is get from bean. But by default the panel is unblocked (but checkbox works: if check it or unckeck blocking works).
I need that if checkbox unchecked, the panel may be blocked.
Friend said that it can be implemented using document.ready in js, but I dont know js very well.
Help please if you can.

Comment: You should not use p:blockUI. p:blockUI is only for intermediate process , this is not intented to block somewthing on page load. 
You can disable dynamically from back bean.

Comment: I've solved it. This is bad way... but it works!
Maybe later i'll correct it.

I used js document.ready, and function with if-statement inside, which checks chbx.checked property of the checkbox and, if needed, block panel.

Thank you for your time :)